# Editing tag wikis produces design bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, editor

The tag wiki edit page has, well, a few layout problems.

[image: Image of tag wiki edit page with layout bugs circled]

1. The title intrudes upon the header.
2. The excerpt box protrudes into the help box.
3. The help box text extrudes from the help box.

(Yes, I used the word *intrudes* slightly incorrectly (or at least the OED thinks so), but it's too amusing having three different -trude words.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix will be in the next build.